# Changing the default governor ubuntu-server

Tags: server

To contextualize, I have ubuntu-server on a old laptop, just to save some files and backups.

I was trying to enter in powersave mode in order to consume less power.

My scaling_governator output is:

> echo $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor): schedutil

I've tried:

```
for x in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo powersave > $x; done
```

result:

> -bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied

Tried:

```
sudo sh -c "for x in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo powersave > $x; done
```

Then It "works", but when I check it says schedutil again. Nothing changed.

Any tip?

Comment: Use single quotes to fix the $x expansion by the outer shell

Comment: and you need to do this as root so do `sudo -i` first.

Comment: Omg, I am feeling really dumb reading this!!

Comment: I complicated everything, thank you.

Comment: You can also do this: `echo powersave | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` . Are you saying the governor will change back to `schedutil` after that?